# How can i create components and containers in App.js when tsparticles pacakage is installed?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I created the app by using `create-react-app your_app --template particles` and it works, but when I created a components folder, which contains four different folders and four different files, it started giving me different bugs. This is what shows on my chrome browser. `ERROR in ./src/App.js 63:0-43    Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './Components/Ranks/Rank' in 'D:\face-recognition-app\src' ERROR in ./src/Components/Logos/Logo.js 5:0-34        Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'react-tilt' in 'D:\face-recognition-app\src\Components\Logos'`

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import Particles, { initParticlesEngine } from "@tsparticles/react";
import { loadFull } from "tsparticles";
import Navigation from "./Components/Navigations/Navigation";
import Logo from "./Components/Logos/Logo.js";
import ImageLinkForm from "./Components/ImageLinkForm/ImageLinkForm";
import Rank from "./Components/Ranks/Rank";
import "./App.css";
import particlesConfig from "./particles.json";

function App() {
  const [init, setInit] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (!init) {
      initParticlesEngine(async (engine) => {
        await loadFull(engine);
      }).then(() => {
        setInit(true);
      });
    }
  }, [init]);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      {init && <Particles options={particlesConfig} />}
      {/* Your other components */}
      {<Navigation />}
      {<Logo />}
      {<Rank />}
      {<ImageLinkForm />}
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: what error do you get?

Comment: Please provide more detail, and include some code from your child components like navigation etc.

Comment: If this is a new project, consider using something other than create-react-app (CRA).  CRA is now deprecated and will no longer be actively maintained.  There are [several options](https://www.google.com/search?q=alternatives+to+create-react-app) such as Vite or Parcel.

Comment: Have been able to fix the bugs all. It is my link path for some folders and files in the Components that caused the problem and some npm packages like tachyons and tilt i didn't install before using them. Thank you for the quick response everyone